# React checkbox tree expand and check button not responding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this code :

```
render() {
    let state = {
        checked: [
            'catc'
        ],
        expanded: [
            'cata',
            'catb'
        ],
    };
<CheckboxTree
   nodes={this.props.chosenCategory.children}
   checked={state.checked}
   expanded={state.expanded}
   onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
   onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
/>
```

So I have the result like this :
[image]

But when I click on `check` or expand the list doesn't respond. Can anybody help me please? Thanks in advance.

After putting state outside of `render()` :

[image]

`this.props.chosenCategory.children` :

```
"id": 26578,
                "label": "CatA",
                "value": "cata",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 26579,
                        "label": "CatB",
                        "value": "catb",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 26580,
                                "label": "CatC",
                                "value": "catc",
                                "children": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define state outside of render method :

```
  state = {
    checked: [
      'catc'
    ],
    expanded: [
      'cata',
      'catb'
    ],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CheckboxTree
        nodes={this.props.chosenCategory.children}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        expanded={this.state.expanded}
        onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
        onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: And also need to use `this.state.checked` and `this.state.expanded` but not `state.checked` and `state.expanded`

Comment: Now the list works but it doesn't care about `expanded` and `checked` state. I edited my question with a new screenshot

Comment: did you check my updated code as well as my comment?

Comment: yes, otherwise it gives a compilation error

Comment: You need to update this 
```
checked={state.checked}
expanded={state.expanded}
```
to 
```
checked={this.state.checked}
expanded={this.state.expanded}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227635/discussion-between-klsdskldsd-and-ifxli).

Comment: can you add the log of `this.props.chosenCategory.children` object?

Comment: route object - `cata` also should be an array, but it seems it's an object not an array right now.

Comment: can you jump into the chat?